# MySQL change a value depending on its original value

Tags: sql, mysql, logic

Hy everyone, 
Long time reader, first time poster.

This sounds like it should be really simple but I can't find the solution anywhere. I'm building a ratings system where people can rate if something is active or not. It has its own little logic but for it to work I need to.

1. check the items rating
2. depending on the current rating change it to a pre set amount.

I could hard code it in PHP with two SQL statements but I'm sure using a single stored procedure (one for vote up, another for vote down) will be much faster.

example table:

```
item_id | item_rating
---------------------
   10   |    1
```

logic to vote item_rating up:

```
if | then
---------
 0 |  1
 1 |  2
-1 |  1
-2 |  1
 2 |  2
```

logic to vote item_rating down:

```
if | then
---------
 0 | -1
 1 | -1
-1 | -2
-2 | -2
 2 | -1
```

I know a simple points based system would be easier but due to the nature of the system this is the simplest solution I could find.

Can someone explain how I would use IF statements in SQL to achieve this? I'm sure the answer is really obvious to someone in the know.

(btw using the latest version of MySQL)

Comment: I don't see the logic in what you're doing. How much are votes getting rated down?

Comment: 2 is active, -2 is inactive, 0 is unrated. 1 and -1 is don't know. The idea is two people have to consecutively vote either way for it to be valid.

Comment: If 2 is active, then 2 consecutive up votes will activate, but only 1 down vote will inactivate it. You'd probably need to think about a  logic that defines a behavior for 1 and -1.

Comment: Yeah that's the way its supposed to work. There for valid links on fast changing sites. Say 50 people vote up a link then it dies over night I don't want a system than needs another 50 people to vote it down again. But at the same time I don't want one person to be able to come along and kill a link on their own. That's why it has to be two consecutive votes the same way. 1 doesn't inactivate just changes our warning to 'dunno' rather than 'don't waste your time'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?  Here's an upvote:

```
UPDATE rating
SET item_rating = IF(item_rating < 1, 1, 2);
```

Here's a downvote:

```
UPDATE rating
SET item_rating = IF(item_rating > -1, -1, -2);
```

Comment: Thanks. Had to use nested If statements in the end. Not pretty but it works. Thanks for the answer! just spent 4 hours of my life tearing my hair out over this. Heres what I made with your code

Comment: UPDATE item 
SET rating = IF(rating = 1,  2, IF(rating = 0,  1, IF(rating = -1,  1, IF(rating = -2,  1, 2)))) 
WHERE id = 10;

Comment: Sorry. Got caught up with your first post. That is a FAR more elegant solution! I'd take my hat off to you if I owned one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is equivalent and more flexible, in case you wanted to have more than two votes needed to move something: `rating = IF(rating > 0, MAX(2,rating + 1), 1)`. You would just change the 2 to a higher number.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I think it should work.

```
update items i
set item_rating = (select i.item_rating + `then` from item_rating
                   where `if` = i.item_rating)
where i.item_id = 10
```

Comment: This is for up-votes. For down-votes you would use `-` instead of `+`.